# Servlet is not printing anything with PrintWriter object

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc, printwriter

> This is my JSP code, i am using get method to send data to go to servlet , servlet name is googleser.

```
    <body>
        <div class="formdiv">
            <h1 align="center">Shikhar Google</h1>
            <form action="googleser" method="get" align="center"> 
                <input type="text" name="search1" class="search1"><br>
                <input type="submit" class="submitbtn">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
```

> This is my servlet code . I tired printing every option related with printwriter method , but none of these worked.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class googleser extends HttpServlet 
{
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
  {
      try
      {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/shikhar","root","");
          Statement st = con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("select * from student");
          PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
          while(rs.next())
          {
              out.print(rs.getString(2));
          }
          String a= request.getParameter("search1");

          out.print("<h1>Shikhar</h1>");
          out.print("sddsdssdsd");


      } 
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
//         System.out.print("yes yes yes");
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: Do not swallow the exceptions add `ex.printStackTrace();` inside the catch block.

Answer (score 3):

please call the flush method after writing content into the response.

```
 out.flush();
```